# iOSのみ、checkboxのlabelが反応しません。

Tags: onsen-ui

CSSコンポーネントにあるサンプル「Material List with Checkboxesコンポーネント（http://components.onsen.io/）」を使ってチェックボックスを作りたいのですが、iOSのみlabelがうまく反応しません。サンプルコードはそのまま使っています。

一緒に読み込んでいるonsenui.min.jsを削除すると動作するようですが、削除せずに動くようにしたいと思っています。
知識が足りず自分では解決できそうにありません。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsen-css-components.css">

</head>
<body>

<ul class="list list--material">
  <li class="list__item list__item--material">
    <div class="list__item__left list__item--material__left">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--material">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="checkbox__input checkbox--material__input">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--material__checkmark"></div>
      </label>
    </div>

    <label for="checkbox3" class="list__item__center list__item--material__center">
      <div class="list__item__title list__item--material__title">Notifications</div>
      <div class="list__item__subtitle list__item--material__subtitle">Allow notifications</div>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="list__item list__item--material">
    <div class="list__item__left list__item--material__left">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--material">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="checkbox__input checkbox--material__input" checked="checked">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--material__checkmark"></div>
      </label>
    </div>

    <label for="checkbox4" class="list__item__center list__item--material__center">
      <div class="list__item__title list__item--material__title">Sound</div>
      <div class="list__item__subtitle list__item--material__subtitle">Hangouts message</div>
    </label>
  </li>

</ul>

<script src="onsenui.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onsen UI 開発チームより回答済み。 https://teratail.com/questions/60161

Comment: 回答をいただき解決することができました。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/60161

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UI 内部で使用しているライブラリ、 FastClick のバグによるもので、`onsenui.min.js` の読み込み後に、

```ja
ons.fastClick.destroy();
```

を実行することで応急処置になるとのこと。
Onsen UI 開発チームの方より [Teratail で回答](https://teratail.com/questions/60161) あり。